# SSRS divide sum by a field

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm trying to build a report which basically reports the number of closed incidents that a property has done in a given month then divide it by the number of beds in that property.

The number of incidents is calculated from the incidents table based on the month and the property then the number of rooms is obviously static per property.

The tables that I have a:

```
Incident: No_ which is the ID, PropertyID, Created_DateTime, Closed_DateTime, Status.

Property: ID, Name, No_of_Rooms
```

I tried this code in a calculated field but it errors saying that you can't use an aggregated column, which I thought it might:

```
=Sum(Fields!No_.Value, "Incidents")/Fields!No_of_Rooms.Value
```

I'm sure this will be simple but I can't find what to search to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this on the 'Details' level of the report and is commonly the lowest level. You may want this instead:

```
=(Fields!No_.Value / Fields!No_of_Rooms.Value)
```

If it is on a parent group I am guessing you just are listing a single instance and it **wants** an aggregate. In that case:

```
= (Sum(fields!No_.Value) / Sum(Fields!No_of_Rooms.Value))
```

This would perform aggregation on an aggregation.  You do not need to do this `(Fields!(thing).Value, "DataSet")` if everything is in the same Dataset, if not then you do.  Generally if are in the table or object that your dataset is referencing it knows that part implicitly without being listed.

Comment: unfortunatly I'm still getting an error when I run that: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The expression used for the calculated field '=(Sum(fields!No_.Value) / Sum(Fields!No__of_Rooms.Value))' includes an aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function. Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions.
   at

Comment: All I want it to do is divide the sum it performs where it counts the number of incidents by the number of bed spaces there are at the given property, I didn't think this would be too difficult but I think I must be searching for the wrong thing...

Comment: Did you try this one first?  =(Fields!No_.Value / Fields!No_of_Rooms.Value)

Answer (score 0):

Your formula will work but only if placed in the tablix but for performance this should be calculated in the query if possible.